# How to get first element of typelist in C++-11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am following C++ templates the complete guide and trying to get the first element from a typelist.

The following compiles:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename... Elements>
class Typelist;

using SignedIntegralTypes =
        Typelist<signed char, short, int, long, long long>;

template <typename List>
class HeadT;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
class HeadT<Typelist<Head, Tail...>> {
public:
    using Type = Head;
};

template <typename List>
using Head = typename HeadT<Typelist<List>>::Type;


int main() {
    static_assert(is_same<Head<SignedIntegralTypes>, SignedIntegralTypes>::value, "");
}
```

`Head<SignedIntegralTypes>` produces `SignedIntegralTypes`. I would expect it to produce `signed char`. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik removing `bits/stdc++.h` and switching to `type_traits` makes 0 difference to the outcome. Thank you for your insightful contribution :)

Comment: FYI, I think it is usually written `C++11` not `C++-11`.  although _C++ negative eleven_ is amusing to contemplate.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's deconstruct all the templates, one step at a time.

```
Head<SignedIntegralTypes>
```

Ok, now let's take the definition of what `Head` is:

```
template <typename List>
using Head = typename HeadT<Typelist<List>>::Type;
```

Since `SignedIntegralTypes` is the template parameter, that's what `List` becomes here. So this becomes:

```
typename HeadT<Typelist<SignedIntegralTypes>>::Type
```

And since `SignedIntegralTypes` is, itself a:

```
using SignedIntegralTypes =
        Typelist<signed char, short, int, long, long long>;
```

The full class becomes:

```
typename HeadT<Typelist<Typelist<signed char, short, int, long, long long>>>::Type
```

And if you work out the result of the specialization, the first type in the `Typelist` is

```
Typelist<signed char, short, int, long, long long>
```

And that's what `Type` gets aliased to. A.k.a. a `SignedIntegralTypes`.

And you fix this, to get the intended result, simply by fixing the `Head` alias:

```
template <typename List>
using Head = typename HeadT<List>::Type;
```